git commit show error "Java installation directory is not found."
I use git on Windows 11. Commands like pull, clone, status .. work. But git commit return error:
Java installation directory is not found.
Other information:
> get-command git

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     git.exe                                            2.39.2.1   C:\app\tools\Git\cmd\git.exe

> get-command java

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     java.exe                                           21.0.5.0   C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-21.0.5.11-hotspot\bin\java.exe

> write-host $env:JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-21.0.5.11-hotspot

Do you know where the issue is ? Any reply is appreciated.

"git commit returns error" Do you run git commit in the same powershell terminal or in git-bash? Is $JAVA_HOME defined in git-bash? It seems you have a pre-commit hook in .git/hooks, can you run it directly like .git/hooks/pre-commit? What is the pre-commit hook, can you show us its code?

Try the same command with --no-verify.

git commit in the same powershell command i mean.

It seems --no-verify works. Thanks @Guildenstern What is the reason ? How can i use the commit without the option ?

Hooks are additional things that are setup to run on a repo... That is stuff you add, to the repo, it is not part of stuff that git downloads when it clones, it's not part of git.

@phd Thanks for your response. It seems the IT installed a lot of commit hooks when they install git.  I can see that in gitconfig file. The code is internal, so i dont think i can disclose. Do you know how I can view which hook is used when i run git commit ?

For git commit it's .git/hooks/pre-commit. See git help hooks, https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks . But the pre-commit hook could be a wrapper like [tag:pre-commit.com] or [tag:husky] that have their own configurations and plugins.

Thanks for all the comments above.
I found the location of pre-commit file. It uses shell script to find java path. So I cannot run git in powershell, but only MINGW64.
